# EPPlus: Saving after setting ExcelDxfStyleConditionalFormatting

Tags: c#, epplus, conditional-formatting

I created a method for reformatting an Excel Workbook:

```
        string Formula = @"IF(LEN($A2)>0,1,0)";

        using (ExcelPackage excelFile = new ExcelPackage(destinationfile))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            ExcelTable worktable = worksheet.Tables[0];
            string workrange = worksheet.Cells[worktable.Address.Start.Row + 1, worktable.Address.Start.Column, worktable.Address.End.Row, worktable.Address.End.Column].Address;

            ExcelAddress cellIsAddress = new ExcelAddress(workrange);
            var cfRule = worksheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(cellIsAddress);

            cfRule.Formula = Formula;

            //cfRule.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            //cfRule.Style.Fill.PatternColor.Color = Color.LightYellow;
            //cfRule.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Auto = true;
            //cfRule.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            //cfRule.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.LightCyan;

            excelFile.Save();
        }
```

The problem is that, if I set any style to the rule (My goal was to set a yellow background, but I also tried with all the commented options), the Save() method crashes.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"?  What is the error?  Tray uncommenting one line at a time and running - which one causes the error?

Comment: I did that, I tried with all the commented lines separately. Actually, I solved my problem by using OpenXML directly.